# Preinstall Google Play apps on a custom firmware

Tags: android

My client who is a carrier (believe me or not), who is going to distribute a bunch of tablets is asking me to put free apps downloaded from Google Play into their custom firmware.

- is it just simply about downloading the apks and put them in the system/app folder (as odex or as apk) ? we are not talking here about simply uncheking "unknown sources", it's just to confirm the process.
- aren't there any permission or certificate related issues or google account enablement issues to make the apps work ? there could be r/w issues, or issues with tablets where a google account is not activated (does a preinstall app does a roundtrip with the market when it's starts and what is the google account is not activated?)
- legally is it authorized to redistribute apps published on Google play from other developers without their consent, even if they are free ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of your questions are answered in the [Google Play Terms](https://play.google.com/about/play-terms.html)

In short:
It is certainly technically possible to put the APKs preinstalled on the devices but you are not allowed to do so unless you get a separate agreement with all the app developers in question. If you get an agreement with them they can probably provide you with an APK file that you can preload in the custom firmware.

Comment: In case we get a agreement from the developers, what would be the related technical issues involved to distribute the apps ? why would the developers send the APKs if we can download them from the market ?

Comment: Well, it depends. You can read about Google's copy protection here: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html#CopyProtection
I would say, APK from the developer is the best choice!

Comment: I would think if google doens't put limitations that a new device brand can download a bunch of paid apps and put them in a custom firmware to be redistributed as added value on their collection of device, so are there some technical and legal limitations ?

Comment: Google does not own the apps, they cannot make this choice themselves